# Mobius transformation mapping the upper half plane to itself

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

On my book, it says the sufficient and necessary condition for a Mobius transformation $T:w = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ to map the upper half plane $\{z:\mathrm{Im}(z) > 0\}$ to itself is that:

a. $a,b,c,d$ are all real numbers

b. $ad - bc > 0$

I can see the two conditions are sufficient. But I feel confused for the necessity. On my book it says, since $T$ maps real line to real line, thus $a,b,c,d$ are all real numbers. But if $a,b,c,d$ satisfy the condition, how about $ia,ib,ic,id$? They are not real numbers any more. Or, even if it says $T$ could be reduced to the form where they are all real, how to see this? Thank you!

Edit: Actually my confuse is, since my book claims four arguments are real only through one sentence, so I assume there should be a very simple argument that could immediately get to the result that $a,b,c,d$ are real. This is where I'm confused. Thank you!

Comment: It implies that $a,b,c,d$ are either all real or all complex, combinations ruled out for the mapping.

Comment: `But if a,b,c,d satisfy the condition, how about ia,ib,ic,id?` They no longer satisfy $ad-bc \gt 0$ since $(ia)(id)-(ib)(ic)=-(ad-bc)\,$. Note that the coefficients are only defined up to a multiplicative constant, and see also this question listed under the `related` column on the right: [Mobius transformation on the open upper half plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977702/mobius-transformation-on-the-open-upper-half-plane?rq=1).

Comment: @dxiv Yeah I see your argument. I just wonder that on my book it is only one sentence that since it maps real line to real line, the four arguments must be real. I think there must be a simple reason. I learned the properties of Mobius transformation such as it maps circline to circline, and symmetric points to symmetric points. But I still don't get it...

Comment: @EdwardWang You have a point, iff what you quoted is literally what the book said. Note the slight, but essential, difference vs. the statement in the question I linked, which said that $T$ `can be written as` i.e. *one* among all equivalent forms of $T$ has in fact all the coefficients real.

Comment: @dxiv Yes it literally says that. Since it is a Chinese book, I just assume it actually means "can be written"..

Comment: Where does the inequality $ad - bc > 0 $ come from? Why is it relevant here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose three different real numbers $z_1,z_2$ and $z_3$, so $T(z_1), T(z_2)$ and $T(z_3)$ are all real. Then solve for $a,b,c$ and $d$, there must be a set of real solution.