# Show that for every $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$ there exist $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, s.t. $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=w$ with $ad-bc=1$ and Im(z)>0 and Im(w)>0

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Show that for every $z,w \in \mathcal{H}$ there exist $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, s.t. $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=w$ with $ad-bc=1$.

This is just a small lemma in a bigger proof about a relation between bijections in the upper half-plane and $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ regarding the mobius transform. The problem seems kinda obvious given the geometric interpretation of the mobius transform, but I can't figure out how to proof it "algebraically", meaning just shuffling the terms around / guessing explicit values for a,b,c,d to fulfill the equation...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: will this help? $$\frac{a}{c}-\frac{1}{c(c z+d)}=w$$

Comment: I think $z$ and $w$ are points in the upper half plane? The wording of the problem looks a bit clumsy.

Comment: @lozenges I'm not really sure how. I can totally see how eliminating one variable with ad-bc=1 helps, but I can't really see any solutions to this equation still. Setting a variable to a certain value (e.g. a=0, c=1 etc.) doesn't really seem to help, since now your two variables have to be dependent of z or w and therefore aren't real. Did you have something more explicit in mind?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mobius transformation on the open upper half plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977702/mobius-transformation-on-the-open-upper-half-plane) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Baz%2Bb%7D%7Bcz%2Bd%7D%3Dw%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24ad-bc%3D1%24&p=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$, $w=u+iv$; note that $y,v>0$. Let's express $w$ through $z$, excluding the explicit mention of $i$ in the process:

$w = u+iv = u + v(z-x)/y = \frac{vz-vx+uy}{y} = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, where $a=v/\sqrt{vy}$, $d=y/\sqrt{vy}$, $c=0$, $b=(uy-vx)/\sqrt{vy}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate $Im(w)$ you get $$Im(w)=\frac{(ad-bc) Im(z)}{|cz+d|^2},$$ so you just need to choose $c, d$ so that $|cz+d|^2=\dfrac{Im(z)}{Im(w)}$ (for instance , $c=0$, $d^2=\dfrac{Im(z)}{Im(w)})$, then follow through to find $a, b$.